# I have an exercise class I want to patent so no-one can infringe on my creation

Tags: group, exercise

I have a specific exercise class i have created on my own that I wish to patent and promote globally.

Comment: There are no patent or government authorities behind this system so they will not get your message here. Ask Patents is a community-run website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patents or Applications. Please view the **[site tour](https://patents.stackexchange.com/tour)** to understand how this site works.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I’m not sure the OP is trying to contact government authorities. My guess is she is asking how to proceed with patenting. Unfortunately, I doubt an exercise class is patentable.

Comment: @EricShain I'm not sure either,  so I closed it as unclear and commented that this does not start any sort of proceedings... in case the author was unaware.

Comment: Sounds pretty unpatentable anyways

Comment: Pure methods that don't solve a problem aren't likely to get through the USPTO since changes to interpretation of eligibility in 2013 ([Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International) and subsequent cases.)  In Alice, the idea was that mental steps, in this case, for managing risk, are ineligible.  I'm not sure of the scope of "business methods", or if a method of conducting a class would qualify, but it would be potentially expensive to find out!  *(Going international with a patent is **extremely expensive** b/c you have to file in each region.)*

Comment: You might want to research successful exercise systems like [Tae Bo](  You might want to research exercise franchises like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tae_Bo) to get a sense of how they protected their IP.  Finding a catchy name and trademarking would be your first step I'd think, and trademarking is relatively inexpensive and can be renewed indefinitely.  But, again, you'll have to trademark in each region, which will get expensive.

Comment: Also, you could file copyright on every way to describe your system you can think of, to try and block competitors from explaining it that way if they try to clone.  (Copyright is the cheapest of the IP protection methods, with current rates in the US ~$30 per filing.)

Comment: Final note: Many/most Patent Attorneys will do a brief, initial consultation for free, so you should definitely think about looking up one or two, and getting their perspective.  (My guess is, they will advise there is an extremely low likelihood of this being patent eligible, but it never hurts to ask.)  By contrast, beware of "patent mills" like Legal Zoom b/c they will may advise you to go ahead and file a patent to get your business, regardless of the likelihood of success.